# SonarQube Dependency-check plugin not generating report

Tags: sonarqube, maven-dependency-check-plugin

I installed dependency-check plugin in sonarqube but report is not generating, it says no HTML report found.
[Dependency-Check error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHbBo.png)

I'm trying to install dependency-check plugin in sonarqube to get dependency report. I installed plugin in 'Marketplace' when ever I run scanning report is not generating.It says "No HTML-Report found. Please check property sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath"

I added below properties to generate report in specified target path in "sonar-project.properties" file
sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath=/home/ubuntu/dependency-check-report/dependency-check-report.json
sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=/home/ubuntu/dependency-check-report/dependency-check-report.html
sonar.dependencyCheck.summarize=true

correct me if I'm wrong I'm new to sonarqube.

Answer (score 0):

You're thincking that the plugin generate the report, but this is false. As you can see in the plugin documentation [here](https://github.com/dependency-check/dependency-check-sonar-plugin) it says:

> This SonarQube plugin does not perform analysis, rather, it reads
> existing Dependency-Check reports. Use one of the other available
> methods to scan project dependencies and generate the necessary JSON
> report which can then be consumed by this plugin. Refer to the
> Dependency-Check project for relevant documentation.

So you need to generate the report using [Dependency Check](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/) and just consume the report on plugin.